Fix for BlockheightExceededError
Hope you are doing well!
Could you please advise me to fix this error?
While doing a transaction on the presale website using the Solana pair I am getting the BlockheightExceededError,
Error: BlockheightExceededError.
I would really appreciate if can help me to fix this error.
Thank you

This question is similar to: How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
